# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'MinNum' was corrupted

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

void main()
{
    unsigned _int8 MinNum;
    unsigned _int8 MaxNum;
    unsigned _int8 Guess;
    unsigned _int8 MagicNum;

    printf("Please enter the minimum value (0 - 255): ");
    scanf("%d", &MinNum);

    printf("Please enter the maximum value (%d - 255): ", MinNum);
    scanf("%d", &MaxNum);

    printf("Guess a number between %d - %d", MinNum, MaxNum);
    scanf("%d", &Guess);

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    MagicNum = (rand() % MaxNum + MinNum);

    if (Guess > MagicNum)
    {
        printf("You guessed too high.");
    }
    else if (Guess < MagicNum)
    {
        printf("You guessed too low.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You win.");
    }
}
```

This code is giving me the error specified in the title. I looked around the internets and found out that this error is caused when the data you are assigning to a variable exceeds the data limits, but don't know where it is exceeding the limits on MinNum.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings (or just pay attention to them if they already are). They would make the issue obvious.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%d", &num)` expects `num` to have `int`-type. Passing the address of a type with `sizeof(othertype) < sizeof(int)` is undefined behaviour. 
 If you want to `scanf()` into a `char`-sized variable, you have to use `scanf("%hhd", &num)` or `scanf("%c", &num)`.
The same principle applies to `printf()`, by the way. Use `printf("%hhd", num)` or `printf("%c", num)` when `num` is of type `char`.
Also, the return type of `main()` in C is `int`.